# setting ubuntu system variable when value starts with?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to set system variable in ubuntu shell.

```
export VARIABLE=!password!
```

output:

```
-bash: !password!': event not found
```

so I tried with quotes:

```
export VARIABLE="!password!"
```

output:

```
-bash: !password!: event not found
```

or even

```
export VARIABLE='!password!'
```

with no output, but when i tried to see the variable I get:

```
VARIABLE='!password!'
```

which is not the desired one.

I also tried with backslashes here and there, but with no success. Please help, the task is to create system variable with password: !password!
(starting and ending with exclamation marks.)

Comment: `when i tried to see the variable i get: VARIABLE='!password!' which is not the desired one`.  Sorry, but isn't that exactly what you say you want?

Comment: export VARIABLE='!password!'
with no output, but when i tried to see the variable I get:

VARIABLE='!password!', this is as expected, but what do you want to do with it or what is your actual question

Comment: It appear to be desired one, I was confused because shell showed this apostrophes which I thought was like different string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do:

```
VARIABLE='!bla!'
```

And then

```
echo $BLA
```

you get

```
!bla!
```

which is what you seem to describe as the wanted result.

To make it available to subshells, don't forget to add `export` to the above.

Comment: Is there a difference for the scripts when variable is with apostrophes or without like: VARIABLE='system' or VARIABLE=system

Comment: @Arm Yes, but not if the variable is a simple single non-space non-special character string. See e.g. [this tutorial on quotes in sh](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Quote.html).